# Using a loop in a python expression to stack labels while avoiding zero value attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, expression

I have a number of point features in a map in ArcMap 10.6 that I would need to label based on information form three fields (Test1, Test2 and Test3) with numeric values. The labels from these 3 fields would have to be stacked. And each of these labels would have to appended with a date text. The format of the label would be something like this;

[image]

Some of the records in these fields contain zero values and so it would be required to loop through these fields and skip the zero values. That is not to have them displayed in the label. Currently I have the following scripts to work with;

-script to stack labels
-This does not skip through zero values

```py
def FindLabel ([Test1] , [Test2] , [Test3]):
      return "05/10/2018" + " - " + [Test1] + "\r\n" + "05/10/2018" + " - " + [Test2] + "\r\n" + "05/10/2018" + " - " + [Test3]
```

-script to skip "0" values in the fields and  stacks the labels, however does not append text string to each attribute value.

```py
def FindLabel ( [Test1] , [Test2] , [Test3] ):
  fields =  ([Test1] , [Test2] , [Test3]) 
  label = ""
  for field in fields:
    if field == "0":
      continue
    else:
      label = label + field + "\n"
  return label
```

Is there a way achieve this using a python label expression in ArcMap 10.6

Comment: When you evaluate the value of Test 1,2 and 3 you are testing it to see if it is equal to "0" which is a string! Assuming your fields ARE numeric fields then the test should be `if field == 0:`

Comment: @Hornbydd with labelling they are all strings, type doesn't matter.

Comment: Perhaps field =='0' will work.

Comment: In your first case you add \r\n while in the second case it is only \n

Comment: @FelixIP never knew that!

Comment: @Hornbydd@FelixIP@JGH Thansk for getting back to me over the issue. I just wanted to provided a clarification regarding the 2nd snippet.I was able to use the second snippet to stack the labels and avoid zero values. However the date string is only appended to the first attribute field value in the iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [List comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) with an if statement and then join the list elements together to a string with newline in between:

```
def FindLabel ( [Test1],[Test2],[Test3] ):
  values = [Test1],[Test2],[Test3]
  date = "05/10/2018"
  labellist = ["{0} - {1}".format(date, value) for value in values if value != '0']
  label = "\n".join(labellist)
  return label
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BERA for getting back to me over the issue and for providing me with the code. This worked perfectly.

Comment: And also for providing info on using the List Comprehension method. I have not worked with method yet. It seems like an efficient way to combine an expression, for clause and if clause to create a list.